# Adding SVN to Spring Tool Suite, Subclipse extension not available

Tags: spring, svn, spring-tool-suite

I have Spring Tool Suite (STS) 3.6.3 installed. On another PC at home I recall being able to add SVN integration into STS by bringing up the Dashboard window, and checking the "Subsclipse" check box on the Extensions tab. However, I don't see this option on my current installation. I am including installed extensions, too, and I do not see Subclipse in the list.

When I select the Project folder in the Project Explorer window, right mouse click → *Team* → *Share Project*, I see only CVS and Git as options, but I would like to use SVN.

My experience with all things Java is measured in hours rather than years, so don't assume anything :-)

How do I integrate SVN with STS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to run with elevated or administrator rights.

Comment: @ChadDplease edit your question according to your requirement not use answer area for this purpose.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. The solution to my issue that I was experiencing trying to get SVN integration was solved by first running STS *with Elevated rights*. That was the ANSWER, not a new requirement. I posted an answer for the benefit of the community and was voted down.

Comment: @ChadDSorry i misunderstood the issue, please edit your answer like this is the solution or something like that to clarify it, then i up vote it and except the answer as a solution.

Answer (score 6):

Check once if it's installed properly:

Here is how to add the SVN plugin (Subclipse) to your Spring Tool Suite

```
Open the Spring Tool Suite and go to the dashboard.
Click on Extensions (It is under the Help and Documentation heading).
Search for Subclipse. Check the checkbox and click Install.
```

Note: If you do not see Subclipse it implies that it is already installed on your IDE, but you can verify by checking the ‘Show Installed’ beside the search field.

Source URL: http://www.jicdesign.com/blog/web-development/how-to-add-svn-plugin-for-spring-tool-suite.html

Comment: I viewed that site before I posted

Comment: I also read this and it didn't immediately click for me. If it helps it be more clear for anyone, in my 3.8.3 version, the menu is "Help" -> "Dashboard" -> "IDE Extensions".  I initially had trouble find the menu, but once I got there, this answer worked correctly. I was running as Admin because I was also trying @ChadD 's answer.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Spring Tool Suite.
2. Select menu *Help* → *Install new software*
    
   [image]
3. Click on the *Add* button.
4. Set the *Location* field as http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/
5. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>
6. Select the required components.
7. Click on <kbd>Install</kbd> button.
8. Select the *I accept the terms of the license agreements* radio button
9. Click the <kbd>Finish</kbd> button
10. Click *Yes* to restart Spring Tool Suite

Answer (score 4):

Subclipse is available in the Eclipse Marketplace and can be installed via the Marketplace Client. It is also available at the following update site URL's.

NOTE: These are update site URL's to be entered inside the Eclipse installation dialog, not your web browser.

Latest - https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/latest/

4.2.x - https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/4.2.x/

The "latest" site will automatically move on to 4.2.1, 4.3.0, 5.0.0 etc. as those releases are produced. Where as the "4.2.x" site will only pick up new releases in the 4.2.x series such as 4.2.1, 4.2.2 etc.

---

More info at: https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki